# ASP.Net HTML TAGS AND ELEMENTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having error with this code in my asp.net webforms

```
<li>
<asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_Inspection" runat="server" text="inspection" navigateurl="~/view/inspection.aspx" font-underline="false"style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i>
                             </asp:hyperlink>
                         </li>
```

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. What is the solution of these?

Answer (score 1):

keep space between `font-underline` and `style` tag

```
<li>
    <asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_Inspection" runat="server" text="inspection" navigateurl="~/view/inspection.aspx" font-underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i>
    </asp:hyperlink>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

No space

```
    font-underline="false"style="font-size: 18px;
```

Answer (score 0):

<li>
<asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_Inspection" runat="server" text="inspection"
 
 navigateurl="~/view/inspection.aspx"style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"  text-decoration: none; ></i>
                             </asp:hyperlink>
                         </li>